# Angular 2 form validation against pre-entered values

Tags: angular, validation

HTML:

```
<form #accountForm="ngForm">
        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>First Name</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="firstName"
                     name="fname"
                     class="form-control"
                     type="text"
                     required
                     minlength="3"
                     maxlength="24"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Last Name</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="lastName"
                     name="lname"
                     class="form-control"
                     type="text"
                     required
                     minlength="3"
                     maxlength="24"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Email</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="email"
                     name="email"
                     class="form-control"
                     type="email"
                     disabled></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Mobile Phone</label></dt>
          <dd><input [(ngModel)]="phone"
                     name="phone"
                     class="form-control"
                     type="text"
                     required
                     pattern="^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$"></dd>
        </dl>

        <dl class="form-group">
          <dt><label>Bio</label></dt>
          <dd>
            <textarea [(ngModel)]="bio"
                      name="bio"
                      class="form-control"
                      required
                      minlength="5"
                      maxlength="50"
                      maxLength="50"></textarea>
          </dd>
        </dl>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="button"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  [disabled]="!accountForm.form.valid"
                  (click)="updateUserEntry(firstName, lastName, phone, bio)">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

How do you force Angular 2 to validate against pre-entered values?

For example, these inputs are to change your name, phone number etc. so the values they contain are already brought in from the database and shared via the [(ngModel)], but the built-in ng2 validations only seem to validate against newly-inputted values.  (aka, the "Save Changes" button doesn't become enabled until the user re-enters the values that are already there)

Comment: I would recommend you to switch to https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms